# Functional equation involving integrals and exponential

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, special-functions, functional-equations, integral-operators

Can we find on $\mathbb{R}^+$ a real positive function $f(x)$ (in $C^{\infty}$) such that:

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) e^{\lambda \int_1^{x} f(t)^2 dt} dx=0$$

where $\lambda$ is a complex number (with $0<\Re(\lambda)< \frac{1}{2}$) and where we impose following conditions on $f(x)$ near zero and infinity:

$$f(x)\sim x^{-\frac{1}{2}} \; \; \; ( x\to 0) $$

$$f(x)\sim x^{-\frac{1}{2} +a} \; \; \; ( x\to \infty) $$

(with $a>0$)

Any idea on the way to handle such a problem ?

Comment: You have a function to play around with and you just need two integrals to be zero (after separating into real and imaginary parts), so you'd expect gazillions of solutions for non-real $\lambda$. (The required asymptotics are not really stopping us, for example, you can take $f$ equal to these expressions near $0,\infty$.)

Comment: $=0$ identically in $\lambda$? Or $f$ may depend on $\lambda?$

Comment: $f(x)$ does not depends on $\lambda$.

Comment: @Christian The real and  imaginary integrals are linked and $f(x)$ is a positive function so not obvious that we can have solutions... but I agree it seems we have many, then finding a demonstration is far more difficult.